# Increase Dynamic Delivery Module Limit

Tags: android, android-app-bundle, dynamic-delivery

I am in a situation where I need to add more than 50 dynamic modules to my project, but when I am trying to add 51th module, error message comes

```
You have reached the maximum number of feature splits : 50
```

is there any way to increase the maximum number of feature splits?

Answer (score 1):

I came to know that dynamic delivery limit is defined as

```
public static final Integer MAX_NUMBER_OF_SPLITS_BEFORE_O = 50;
public static final Integer MAX_NUMBER_OF_SPLITS_STARTING_IN_O = 127;
```

which I found in google git with file `FeatureSetMetadata.java` so what I do is set minSdk to 26 and limit exceeded to 127.